# Access VBA filter by User

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to setup a simple filter button that will filter by the network user ID which is populated in the [Owner] field when a record is created. The idea is to see only the records you created.

the code I'm using is as follows:

```
Private Sub FilterUser_Click()
Dim Uname As String
Uname = Environ("USERNAME")

Me.Tasks.Form.Filter = [Owner] = Uname '<---- Error debugs this line
Me.Tasks.Form.FilterOn = True

End Sub
```

I get the following error but I'm confused on what field it thinks is missing.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `a = b = c` means `a = (b = c)`, which is "assign to `a` the result of comparison `b = c`" (which may be True or False).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter requires a string value.

```
me.tasks.form.filter = "[owner]='" & uname & "'"
```

Comment: Getting "Syntax error (missing operator in query expression '[Owner]='

Comment: Might need to wrap the variable in quotes.